# How to fetch documents based on from and to date using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-datetime

I have a large mongodb collection that have "date" field as :

```
'date': '2020-06-11 10:05:03.718804'
```

I would like to find documents between from and to date.

**Data in Mongo:** (Sample Collection)

```
{
"_id":"001",
"color":"Blue",
"status":"available",
"date": "2020-06-11 10:05:03.718804"
},
{
"_id":"002",
"color":"Gold",
"status":"available",
"date": "2020-06-12 11:25:03.714804"
},
{
"_id":"003",
"color":"Violet",
"status":"available",
"date": "2020-06-13 11:25:03.714804"
},
{
"_id":"004",
"color":"White",
"status":"available",
"date": "2020-06-14 11:44:23.618704"
}
```

**Pymongo**

```
from datetime import datetime
from_date = "2020-06-11 10:05:03.718804"
to_date = "2020-06-13 11:44:23.618704"
details = db.collection.find({date: {$gt: from_date, $lt:to_date}})
print(details)
```

Output: Should list the data between from and to dates.

Error facing: Invalid token, $gt and $lt is invalid.

How to find the documents based on date condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the dict keys in quotes.  `{"date": {"$gt": from_date, "$lt": to_date}}`

Comment: Your date field is stored as string, so you need to convert it first to   be possible to compare with $dateFromString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISODate` to convert strings to comparable dates.

```
from_date = "2020-06-11 10:05:03.718804"
to_date = "2020-06-13 11:44:23.618704"
details = db.collection.find({"date": { $gte: ISODate(from_date), $lt: ISODate(to_date)}})
print(details)
```